# angularjs 1.5 pass a parameter to component with ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, components

AngularJS 1.5, using ui-router and components.
How do I pass a parameter inside a component using the ui-sref directive?

header.html:

```
<a ui-sref="dashboard({contentType: 'company'})">Company</a>
```

app.js:

```
.state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        component: "dashboard",
        resolve: {
        }
    })
```

dashboard-component.js:

```
 angular.module('myModule').component('dashboard', {
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/dashboard.html',
    controller: DashboardController,
    binding: {
        contentType: '<' // This is not working...
    }
});
```

dashboard.html: (Expects to see contentType in here - but No...)

```
contentType: {{$ctrl.contentType}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your state that it could be called with some params. There are two ways you can have params. Here's a simple explanation:

1. Params that are part of URL

   ```
   .state('dashboard', {
     url: "/dashboard/:contentType",
     component: "dashboard",
     resolve: {
       ...
     }
   })
   ```
2. Params that are not part of URL

   ```
   .state('dashboard', {
     url: "/dashboard",
     params: {contentType: null},
     component: "dashboard",
     resolve: {
       ...
     }
   })
   ```

**EDIT**: If you see, In the plunker I provided in comments, they are not directly trying to use the param value in controller, but they are using it to get something `resolve`d.

Now, coming to your problem's solution,

One way is, you can inject `$stateParams` in controller and use `$stateParams.tester`.

Or, if you want, you can also use `resolve` to directly get the passed value, like:

```
  $stateProvider.state('userlist', {
    url: '/users',
    params: {
      tester: null
    },
    component: 'users',
    resolve: {
      tester: function($stateParams) {
        return $stateParams.tester;
      }
    }
  });
```

[second example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9K9fY5tCXJPk6r5VCEmC?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about "params" but still, that did not worked for me.
1. Do I still need "contentType: '<'" inside dashboard's binding? 2. dashboard component is placed inside ui-view directive - Do I need to specify it (something like <div ui-view content-view="$ctrl.contentType"></div>?

Comment: @chenop Here's an [example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CgHJ7HSeFOu6dyGjv0QW?p=preview) demonstrating how it works with `ui-router` and `components`. If that helps you solve problems, good. Otherwise, you can modify it with your code, fork, and share URL with me

Comment: Appreciate your willingness to help. here is a plunker that demonstrate the issue:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ebxaP8xcCXeIaLiiZ61K?p=preview

Comment: @chenop the `resolve`d was intentional :) thanks for the other fixes

Answer (score 1):

Add url param `contentType` in the state

```
.state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard/:contentType",
        component: "dashboard",
        resolve: {
        }
    })
```